# jQuery doesn't working properly in Laravel 8

Tags: jquery, laravel

I wanted to use DataTables(jquery plugin) in my Laravel project.

So, I put required js and css file links (using cdn) in my blade template, except jquery. Because I know jquery is already there ( *linked in my blade template via 'js/app.js'*)  as I'm using Laravel UI package. additionally, running `$().jquery` in my browser console shows I've jquery 3.5.1.. aslo bootstrap 4.* is using that.

But I'm getting this - **"uncaught referenceError...."**, behaving like I don't have jQuery.(jQuery scripts are also not working)  [*please see attached image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni9VL.png)

So, I added jQuery cdn link and got "**jQuery deffered exception**"

Well, then I removed "js/app.js" from my blade layout.
Now DataTables works,jQuery scripts also work, but bootStrap stops working.

How Can I solve this?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an unusual solution.
If we load app.js in '**deferred**' manner, which is default, the problem arises.

```
<script src="app.js" defer></script>
```

And just removing `defer` attribute solves the problem.

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

**Reason**:
DataTable loads when the page loads. But  with `defer` attribute jQuery loads after the page is loaded. So datatable throws the error that, *it couldn't find jQuery*.

Answer (score 0):

Use this cdn:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.23/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.23/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

These are for bootstrap datatable.

[Read More about Bootstrap Datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4)

Comment: This doesn't help anyway..
Actually, I have them. 2nd line of my problem definition says, I have required js and css files for data tables. 
the problem is with jQuery, its working with bootstrap only, but not working everywhere.

Comment: Check cdn sequence,  jQuery cdn should be first then datatable cdn...

Comment: CDN sequence is OK, dataTables at the end of page, and jQuery in head.